# Connecting DocumentDB with SageMaker (Studio)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-documentdb

So, it has been more than a week that I've been trying to connect my DocumentDB with SageMaker Studio, and I haven't been able to.

Here is the scenario. I have a DocumentDB with which I want to connect using `pymongo` inside a notebook in SageMaker Studio. DocumentDB is restricted to VPC, so I've created my SageMaker Studio Domain in the same VPC as my DocumentDB. Yet, I keep getting time-out errors.

I've tried following this tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/getting-started-with-amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility-part-4-using-amazon-sagemaker-notebooks/), yet, when I do, I still get an error and I'm not able to connect.

Has anyone done this before? BTW, I've already checked the security groups, and DocumentDB is habilitated for any inbound.

By the way, I'm not using the "VPC Only" configuration.

Comment: Hey Davi, can you try doing the same with an EC2 instance rather than SageMaker, and see if you can connect. It seems as if there is a networking issues.

Comment: So, indeed it seems that the notebook is not within the VPC.